# jQuery: Getting text contents of paragraph tag that may or may not contain a link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm successfully getting the text from the first paragraph in a collection of divs using:

```
$('#businessListings div.listing').each(function() {
    console.log('text: ' + $(this).find('p:first').html());
});
```

A sample div looks like this:

```
<div id="businessListings" class="unifyRepeatArea">
    <div class="unifyRepeat listing">
        <p>123 ABC Child Care</p>
        <p>Jane Doe, Owner</p>
        <p>555-555-1234</p>
        <img src="images/123ABCchildcare.jpg" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
...
</div>
```

The problem is, some of the paragraphs in the collection **could** have a link:

```
<p><a href="http://www.123abcchildcare.com">123 ABC Child Care</a></p>
```

How can I get just the text in each div's first paragraph, whether the paragraph has a link or not?

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/JZ6au/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `text()` instead of `html()`:

```
$('#businessListings div.listing').each(function() {
    console.log('text: ' + $(this).find('p:first').text());
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ6au/2/).

Comment: Well, shoot. That was too easy. Kinda obvious why I was getting the html, seeing as I was using "html()"! Funny how that works... :) Thanks, zenith